# Issue pulling wordpress comments

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a simple theme using Twitter's Bootstrap. I am only using wordpress for the blog portion of my website (http://www.mattaltepeter.com/n3). In my single.php file i use  to pull in the comments template. Ultimately I would like to use Jetpack comments, but just trying to use the default wordpress one currently. I have created a test post and added a couple comments to it, but the comments do not show up on the post. I switched my theme to twenty-eleven and they did, so it has to be something with my theme. I think the issue is with my comments.php. I'm not entirely sure what to put in there to make it work. I started working on this awhile ago and cannot remember where I got the code that currently resides in comments.php. I tried to copy and paste the code from the twenty-eleven comments.php, but that didn't work either. Do I need to write custom code for this or what?

Thanks for the help!
Matt

Comment: "4 thoughts on “Test #1” " -> approve one and check whether they are showing under the comment thread or not..let me know the case(chk ur settings for comments)..also check you have comment template like <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?> in your single.php file

Comment: Saw that you posted a comment. The way my comments are set up does not require me to approve them. In `single.php` I use `<?php comments_template(); ?>`. The comments do not show up under the post but they do show up on the comments tab under my dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. This is what I use to call comments.

In functions.php:

```
function custom_comments($comment, $args, $depth) {
  $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    $GLOBALS['comment_depth'] = $depth;
      ?>
        <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" <?php comment_class() ?>>
            <div class="comment-author vcard"><?php commenter_link() ?></div>
            <div class="comment-meta"><?php printf(__('Posted %1$s at %2$s <span class="meta-sep">|</span> <a href="%3$s" title="Permalink to this comment">Permalink</a>', 'your-theme'),
                        get_comment_date(),
                        get_comment_time(),
                        '#comment-' . get_comment_ID() );
                        edit_comment_link(__('Edit', 'your-theme'), ' <span class="meta-sep">|</span> <span class="edit-link">', '</span>'); ?></div>
      <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') _e("\t\t\t\t\t<span class='unapproved'>Your comment is awaiting moderation.</span>\n", 'your-theme') ?>
              <div class="comment-content">
                <?php comment_text() ?>
            </div>
            <?php // echo the comment reply link
                if($args['type'] == 'all' || get_comment_type() == 'comment') :
                    comment_reply_link(array_merge($args, array(
                        'reply_text' => __('Reply','your-theme'), 
                        'login_text' => __('Log in to reply.','your-theme'),
                        'depth' => $depth,
                        'before' => '<div class="comment-reply-link">', 
                        'after' => '</div>'
                    )));
                endif;
            ?>
    <?php } // end custom_comments
```

In your post, within the loop:

```
<?php if ( ('open' == $post->comment_status) && ('open' == $post->ping_status) ) : // Comments and trackbacks open ?>
                        <?php printf( __( '<a class="comment-link" href="#respond" title="Post a comment">Post a comment</a> or leave a trackback: <a class="trackback-link" href="%s" title="Trackback URL for your post" rel="trackback">Trackback URL</a>.', 'your-theme' ), get_trackback_url() ) ?>
<?php elseif ( !('open' == $post->comment_status) && ('open' == $post->ping_status) ) : // Only trackbacks open ?>
                        <?php printf( __( 'Comments are closed, but you can leave a trackback: <a class="trackback-link" href="%s" title="Trackback URL for your post" rel="trackback">Trackback URL</a>.', 'your-theme' ), get_trackback_url() ) ?>
<?php elseif ( ('open' == $post->comment_status) && !('open' == $post->ping_status) ) : // Only comments open ?>
                        <?php _e( 'Trackbacks are closed, but you can <a class="comment-link" href="#respond" title="Post a comment">post a comment</a>.', 'your-theme' ) ?>
<?php elseif ( !('open' == $post->comment_status) && !('open' == $post->ping_status) ) : // Comments and trackbacks closed ?>
                        <?php _e( 'Both comments and trackbacks are currently closed.', 'your-theme' ) ?>

<?php comments_template('', true); ?>
```